No braking at the end of the movement block on spike prime
I created my blocks on spike prime. Back when I used ev3, my motor block had PID correction, acceleration and deceleration all correct. I tried to bring all the concepts and I succeeded. The problem is that when I tried to make me choose whether or not the robot locked the wheels at the end, it didn't work. For example, in the past, I would put a movement block to go straight with 80 maximum speed and in the next block I wanted it to continue at 80, but to make a curve, now it simply seems impossible.
When I tested the first movement block with the floating pattern and the next movement block with the same speed as the first one, it stopped anyway.
If the first movement block is floating by default and there is nothing after it, it never stops, it just keeps walking in a straight line forever.

Maybe if you were more specific about the blocks you used it would help.  Usually SO doesn't like screen shots of code, but maybe it's needed in this case.  Currently your description is unclear about what you tried and what you thought should happen.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
